# Is it possible to truncate and enable a HBase table using Java?

Tags: java, hbase

Is there a way to truncate and re-enable a htable using the Java API similar to using the following commands in the shell?

```
truncate 'tablename'
enable 'tablename'
```

Is there a better way than iterating over each row and using deleteAll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no truncate as such available in the API. But, the class **[HBaseAdmin](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html)** has all the methods you need. Have a look at :

**1. [public void disableTable(String tableName) throws IOException](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#disableTable%28java.lang.String%29)**

**2. [public void deleteTable(String tableName)                 throws IOException](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#deleteTable%28java.lang.String%29)**

**3. [public void enableTable(String tableName)                 throws IOException](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#enableTable%28java.lang.String%29)**

HTH

Comment: This is (maybe it once was?) not correct.  `deleteTable` removes the table completely.  And there is a `truncateTable` method in the API.

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible using admin

```
Admin admin = Connection.getAdmin();
admin.truncateTable(TableName.valueOf("name_of_the_table",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using Thrift and Python with HappyBase:

```
import happybase

c = happybase.Connection()
c.disable_table('tablename')
c.delete_table('tablename')
c.create_table(
    'tablename', {'cf1': dict() }
)
```

And that creates a new and empty table.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with version 0.98 which does not contains that API therefore here is an example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String table = "yourTableName";
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "hbaseZK host");
    HBaseAdmin hBaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
    HTableDescriptor desciptor = hBaseAdmin.getTableDescriptor(table.getBytes());
    hBaseAdmin.disableTable(table);
    hBaseAdmin.deleteTable(table);
    hBaseAdmin.createTable(desciptor);
}
```